# XPSDocument Writer in Graysacale

Tags: c#, grayscale, xpsdocument

I am using XPSDocumentWriter to create a XPS document in c# , What are the options I have if I have to write the XPSDocument in Grayscale , i.e in black and white.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a method of `XPSDocumentWriter` which takes a `PrintTicket` which in turn must be setup with `OutputColor = OutputColor.Grayscale;`

For details and sample code see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.outputcolor.aspx

Comment: I tried this but still my XPS Document created has colors in it. I used the print tickst outputcolor as grayscale

Comment: PrintTicket printTicket=new PrintTicket();
                printTicket.OutputColor = OutputColor.GrayScale;
                
                XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
                writer.Write(surface,printTicket);
                xpsDoc.Close();

Comment: that's not enough code... what is `surface` ? how is `xpsDoc` created ?

Comment: surface is the framework element and xps doc is creadted by the following

Comment: var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(path, FileAccess.Write, CompressionOption.Maximum)

Comment: then the problem is that Grid and how it interacts with the `PrintTicket`... since I never use Xps the way you seem to I can't help you any further... maybe someone else can...